# multiple selection drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to count the number of unique selections from a column that contains multiple selections from a drop down list.

For example, column B3 contains,

> Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday

The count function returns a value of 1 instead of 3 - is there any way to count the three days distinctly? Thank you!

*Multiple selections from a drop down list was made possible using the VBA code from: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JU7G_Tna2zPBtcG2TlarxKCTbuinNsg5LwBqzmuJYK8/edit*

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words here. So in *cell B3* you have `Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday` and for example, in *cell B4* you may have only `Monday' or 'Monday, Tuesday` and you want to count the total number of days listed in column B?

Comment: Hi sorry, didn't think a picture was needed cause it's just two columns.
B3 basically contains 'Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday'
B4 contains the count function - returns 1 instead of 3

Comment: Will B3 always contain 3 values? Can it contain 2? 4? If the format is the same, you can consider counting instances of `comas + 1`

Comment: It can contain any amount of unique values - it's just that if it contains more than one, I would want to count more than one. Sorry I don't follow what's 'comas' - could you please explain it to me, thanks!

Comment: Your string has 3 days as text which are conveniently separated by commas. Count your commas, not the text. (and offset by 1 (+1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is contingent on your string values **always** being separated by a comma (`,`). It appears that the code you shared in the link will continue to add comas with the addition of each new string, which means this should work for you.

> =IF(A1="",0,LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),",",""))+1)

If cell is  blank, return `0`

Else, Count instances of commas (`,`) and offset by 1

[image]

### **Edit 1:** (Explanation)

---

Notice the equation has two *very* similar parts: `LEN(TRIM(A1))` & `LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),",",""))`. The only difference is that one equation uses the `Substitute` function and the other does not.

`Trim` will remove leading and lagging spaces
`Len` returns the character count of your string
`Substitute`, in this instance, is used to replace (*substitute*) all `commas` with a blank string (`""`)

The difference between the length of the string *with commas* to the length of the string *without commas* equals the **total commas** that are present in the string. Saying to "count the commas" was a little misleading on my part since we are really deducing the number of commas.

Comment: Hey urdearboy, thank you so much for this! I completely did not realise this. Would you mind explaining more in detail to a newbie like myself about the formula you typed? E.g. LEN, TRIM, -LEN - thank you so much!

Comment: See **Edit 1:** @pundadesh